# error "Process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1" whie getting android apk file

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a reactNative project with expokit tool. and now i want to get an apk output file from android studio. but i'm getting this error:

```
Process 'command './node_modules/expokit/detach-scripts/run-exp.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @Lucky_girl as long as i remember, running expo publish and then expo start, then getting the output using 'gradlew assemblerelease'. sorry i didn't post the answer when i solved it.

Comment: did any one find solution for this, i am facing same issue and unable to create apk

Comment: @RaviBhandari I'm also stuck on this error. Anyone has found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Run "exp publish" and try again. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have already run expo publish and I'm getting the same error